# Pettis vs. Dunford integrability of operator valued functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, integration, operator-theory

Given a Banach space $X$ and a measure space $(\Omega ,\mu )$, one says that  a function
$$
  f:\Omega \to X
  $$
is *Dunford integrable*, or *scalarly  integrable* if, for every $\varphi $ in the topological dual $X'$,  the function
$$
  x\in \Omega \mapsto \varphi \big (f(x)\big )\in \mathbb C
  $$
belongs to  $L^1(\Omega , \mu )$.

If, in addition, for every measurable subset $E\subseteq \Omega $, there exists  $x_E\in  X$ such that
$$
  \int_E\varphi \big (f(x)\big )\, d\mu (x) = \varphi (x_E),  \quad\forall \varphi \in X',
  $$
then $f$ is said to be *Pettis integrable* and  each $x_E$ is  called   the *Pettis integral of $f$ over $E$*.

If $X$ is reflexive,  every Dunford integrable function is Pettis integrable (this follows easily from the Closed Graph
and the Riesz-Fischer Theorems).

On the downside, there are elementary examples of Dunford integrable $c_0$-valued functions which are not Pettis
integrable.

My questions are thus:

**Question 1**. Is there a Dunford integrable function taking values in $B(H)$ (bounded operators on Hilbert's space)
which is not Pettis integrable?

**Question 2**. Given a non-reflexive space $X$, can one prove that there exists a  Dunford integrable $X$-valued function
which is not Pettis integrable?

---

PS: Besides the result mentioned above regarding reflexive spaces, there is another important sufficient condition for
Pettis integrability due to Dimitrov and Diestel: If $X$ does not contain any isomorphic copy of $c_0$, then each
strongly measurable (meaning a.e. limit of simple functions) and Dunford integrable $X$-valued function is Pettis
integrable.

Comment: @Nate, I think it doesn't help.  I am not sure the Dimitrov-Diestel converse holds.  Besides I think the standard example of non Pettis integrable function into $c_0$ is Pettis integrable when seen as a $B(H)$-valued function since $\ell^\infty$ is also contained in $B(H)$.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue.  Sorry for the noise.